# How to use `cdk diff` to programmatically check whether a stack needs an update?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, cicd

I am using `CDK` to deploy cf stack to AWS. It has `cdk diff` command to tell me what changed in this deployment. If there is nothing changed, it just shows `There were no differences` for each stack included in the `cdk project`.

I have a requirement to run different command based on whether the cdk requires a change. How can I know whether it requires a change from a script? I have checked that `cdk diff` return code is 0 for both `change` and `no change`. What is the right way to know whether the change-set will change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--fail` flag will cause [cdk diff](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-ref) to exit with exit code 1 in case of a diff.  Add [conditional logic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/how-to-conditionally-do-something-if-a-command-succeeded-or-failed) to handle the exit code cases:

```sh
cdk diff --fail && echo "no diffs found" || echo "diffs found"
```

Answer (score 2):

While `cdk diff --fail` generally works, I feel this is a bit dangerous. In case the app has errors or there is a problem with the aws credentials or missing permissions (etc), one would only notice by looking at the output of the CI job.

In our pipeline I'm now checking the output:

```bash
cdk diff "*" 2>&1 | tee cdk.diff
grep "There were no differences" cdk.diff && echo "no diffs found" || echo "diffs found"
```

With the `tee` command the output is simultaneously written to stdout and the file `cdk.diff`.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `cdk diff --fail` and handling the result works most of the time as shown in [the answer from @fedonev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71335926/9797143), but I do agree with [the answer from @udondan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75665297/9797143) that it masks other issues if there is problems with permissions. However by not utilizing `--fail` if you have a CDK app with cross stack references or other dependencies you cant purely rely on "There were no differences" being in the `diff` output.

For example if you have **Stack B** with changes but it depends on **Stack A** for a reference and **Stack A** has no changes the output will show "There were no differences" when running the `cdk diff`.

You could use something like below to continue to utilize `--fail` but still capture other issues:

```
set -o pipefail
if cdk diff "*" --fail 2>&1 | tee cdk.diff; then
  echo "No changes"
else
  if grep "Could not assume role in target account\|no credentials have been configured" cdk.diff > /dev/null; then
    echo "Failed due to IAM permissions problem or IAM credentials not configured"
    exit 1
  else
    echo "Changes detected"
  fi
fi
```

The code may need expanded for detecting other potential issues but I think most other cases like pure code syntax issues get captured earlier anyway.